# when should one use git:// in a git repository URL?

Tags: git

Git has two protocols: a "dumb" protocol and a "smart" protocol, described here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols

But in that description, I don't see any mention of git://, and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with whether one uses the smart or dumb protocols.

I'm guessing that when git:// is used, it's more of a wrapper for https and not a replacement. So I'm curious when somebody might find such a wrapper convenient.

Comment: git:// is a smart protocol and there's no real reason to prefer it these days.  I would say it works the other way around: the smart HTTP protocol kind of wraps the git protocol.  If the smart HTTP protocol didn't exist, then I'd say that it's much more efficient to transfer data.  But with the smart HTTP protocol, there's really not much reason not to use it.  In fact, there's probably an argument to prefer the HTTP version since it's less likely to be blocked by firewalls.  One thing that is nice about the git:// protocol, is that git-daemon is easy to setup and expose public repos. *shrug*

Comment: `git://` is independent of http and https, and always uses a smart transfer. It just means "port 9418" (whatever answers TCP requests on that port on the server), but that had best be the Git daemon, or something very much like it. :-) `http://` connects to port 80, and `https://` connects to port 443, by default, though both let you override this. Https connections expect to fire up a secure shell layers session before continuing with http traffic.